# javascript error in copy content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use javascript to copy a div content in clipboard, i searched this site and found a code that do this, javascript code is:

```js
<script>
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
if (document.selection) { 
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("Copy"); 

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
     window.getSelection().addRange(range);
     document.execCommand("Copy");
     alert("content copied") 
}}
</script>
```

and html code:

```html
<div id="shlinkbox" class="marja">content to be copied</div>

<button id='shlinkcopy'  class="action-button-copy shadow-copy animate-copy green-copy" onclick="CopyToClipboard('shlinkbox')">click to copy</button>
```

but when i click on the button, the chorme console get this error:

Discontiguous selection is not supported.
CopyToClipboard @ (index):5
onclick @ (index):2

and also this code does'nt work in IExplorer

May i ask you to edit this code to work whitout any error in all explorers?

Thank you so much

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: it gets error for mine!